# .NET DateTime to BizTalk DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, biztalk, datetime-format

I have date in this format "1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00" I want to add some hours or days to it . BizTalk expects same datetime format how can i pass it  as Datetime in that format ? No string . Date time with same format as source date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this to get it into a DateTimeOffset object. After that you can call whatever methods you want on it.

```
DateTimeOffset dateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse( "1999-05-31T13:20:00.000-05:00" );
```

To get the value back just use a formatting string.

```
dateTime.ToString( "O" ); //this should be the same format as you started with
```

Here are some other options http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Here is a link to the DateTimeOffset structure
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351654.aspx

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime object is format-independent (for the most part). So whether or not it starts in the format you list or not doesn't matter. You can always get it back into that format (using the `ToString("o")` function). But that's as a string (when format matters).

After a quick search, it looks like you must be talking about string format, even though you said no string. So the other answer or the `ToString("o");` part of mine is relevant.